# Spyder IPython background color

Tags: ipython, background-color, spyder

I'm new to Spyder(version 2.3.0dev6) and I want to change the background color of my IPython console(version 1.1.0). I can change the background color of console but not the IPython console. I also tried in the "Run configuration", "general settings", "command line options": --color=linux, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

(*Spyder dev here*) You need to update Spyder to **2.3.0beta1**, which has this option under:

`Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Background color > Dark background`

Comment: Hi Carlos, is it possible to change the console's theme to something in particular, like we can for the editor? I'd like my editor, console as well as kernel to be the same theme (and I don't mean just "dark"). Thanks.

Comment: We're working on it for Spyder 3.0, to be released in a couple of months :-)

Comment: Do you know how to change the text color in the ipython console? I just updated my spyder and the text is bright green and magenta and doesn't match the editor color scheme at all. The only preferences I can see to change though is for the editor, not the console

Comment: @Elliptica, you're using a very old Spyder version. You need to update to the latest one (3.3.1), where the Editor and Console colors match.

Comment: How can that be? I literally just updated two days ago. I guess i'll try again

Comment: It'd be better if you open an issue in our [issues tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues) and post a screenshot of what you're seeing there, instead of discussing it here.

Comment: @Carlos Cordoba I just installed spyder 3.3.1, and would like to set the background of my console to black, leaving the editor white (just as I did in previous spyder versions). I can't find te way to do this here. Was this option removed? This would be annoying.. Thanks

Comment: That's no longer possible, sorry. The editor and console follow the same color scheme now.